# Custom Email by Term o a Product Attribute

Tags: email, woocommerce

i have a Woocommerce shop that send digital goods. When a client buy i want to send a custom email (or custom section into the email) by the term of the product.

I have configured this:

```
Product
|– Attribute
   |– Taxonomy
      |- Term 1
      |- Term 2
      |- Term 3
```

If the prosuct have the Term 1 then send and email add a section with instructions for that type od product. If have not Term then other instruction.

Someone know how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please describe what you want to do, and what you have already tried to do yourself. See [ask] for help. As currently written, it is unclear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I believe when a customer orders a product from your site, based on the term available for that product you have to add some additional data to the mail that is send. If that is the case, then i can direct you to the right way. Consider Customer New Order email. There are different hooks available in the email template. You can check it [here](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/)

For the time i am using the hook, `woocommerce_email_after_order_table`

```
function render_custom_section_to_email($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email){
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        // You get each product you added to the order
        // Check if the item has term
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get the product ID
        $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'taxonamy_name' ); // Get all terms of custom taxonamy of product
        if('check_if_$terms_contain_the_required_term'){ // If true 
            echo 'Your content Here';
        }
    }   
}
add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'render_custom_section_to_email', 10, 4);
```

You can make slight changes to this function to make things work. Especially in the if condition